# SymPy: How can i output multiple LaTex equations in one cell in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sympy

I am using SymPy in Google Colab. Each cell outputs only 1 pretty LaTex output. Can i have multiple pretty outputs in one cell or do i have to create a new cell for each pretty output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well, but I found some information here: https://www.roelpeters.be/jupyter-notebooks-how-to-print-multiple-outputs-in-a-cell/

**With your import statements, put**

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'
```

Now you can print multiple outputs (LaTeX in this case) to the cell output. Technically this command concatenates the outputs but because we are using dataframes in this case (correct me if I'm wrong) then the output is actually placed on a new line in the cell output area.

**Example**

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'

x = symbols('x')
f = exp(x**2);#f
df = diff(f,x);#df

f
df
```

I cannot guarantee this is the correct or most efficient way to implement such behavior, but it works for my purposes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works, thanks for your time. Just a small addition to your code snippet: x=Symbol('x') , otherwise an exception is raised

Comment: @Ermolai, thank you, updated the code